Timeout during backend unit testing with Vitest
Here the code of my method which is used in the repository which I cover with unit tests.
private async getOrderDataForId(
        orderData: any,
        splitOrders: any,
        responseOrders: any,
        tenant_id: number,
        trackingId?: string,

    ) {
        this.#logger.info({
            trackingId,
            message: "get order data for given orderID - start",
            data: { id: orderData.id, tenant_id: orderData.tenant_id },
        });
        const existingOrderData = await ManufactumCoreOrderService.getOrderById(
            orderData.id,
            orderData.tenant_id,
            trackingId,
        );
        if (!existingOrderData || existingOrderData.length < 1) {
            this.#logger.error({
                trackingId,
                message: "Order doesn't exist with id: ",
            });
            FbxError.throwBadRequest("WMS_Order_3", "Order doesn't exist with id: ");
        }
        const newOrderData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(existingOrderData));
        this.#logger.info({
            trackingId,
            message: "get order data for given orderID - end",
            data: newOrderData,
        });
        // optimize order_items
        for (const [key] of Object.entries(splitOrders)) {
            const position = parseInt(splitOrders[key][0].splitorder_position);
            const number = parseInt(splitOrders[key][0].orderId);
            if (key === "1") {
                console.log("=======got into if block");
                
                newOrderData.splitorder_position = position;
                newOrderData.parent_id = orderData.id;
                newOrderData.order_items = [];
                for (const [index] of newOrderData.order_addresses.entries()) {
                    delete newOrderData.order_addresses[index].id;
                }
                for (const [index] of newOrderData.order_partners.entries()) {
                    delete newOrderData.order_partners[index].id;
                    delete newOrderData.order_partners[index].order_id;
                }
                // prepare new order
                newOrderData.splitorder_number = number;
                let total_weight = 0;
                let total_volume = 0;
                for (const splitOrderItem of splitOrders[key]) {
                    const index = existingOrderData.order_items.findIndex(
                        (item: any) => item.article_barcode == splitOrderItem.barcode && item.item_number === splitOrderItem.ManufactumPositionNumber,
                    );
                    if (index < 0) continue;
                    const orderItemData = existingOrderData.order_items[index];

                    orderItemData.amount = parseInt(splitOrderItem.amount);
                    orderItemData.item_number = splitOrderItem.ManufactumPositionNumber;
                    const articleId = orderItemData.article_id;
                    let articleData = await DB.query(
                        "select weight, length, width,height from articles where id = ?",
                        [articleId],
                    );
                    articleData = articleData[0];
                    const weight = articleData.weight;
                    const _total_weight = await this.calculateAnyISOUnitToAnyIsoUnit(
                        "KG",
                        "GRM",
                        weight * orderItemData.amount,
                    );
                    const width = articleData.width;
                    const height = articleData.height;
                    const length = articleData.length;

                    const realVolume = width * height * length;
                    const maxVolume = (realVolume + realVolume * 0.05) * orderItemData.amount;
                    total_volume += maxVolume;

                    total_weight += parseFloat(_total_weight);
                    orderItemData.WMS_Positionsnummer = parseInt(splitOrderItem.WMS_Positionsnummer);
                    if (existingOrderData.order_items[index]) {
                        existingOrderData.order_items[index].WMS_Positionsnummer = orderItemData.WMS_Positionsnummer;
                    }
                    newOrderData.order_items.push(existingOrderData.order_items[index]);
                }
                newOrderData.total_weight = total_weight + 200;
                newOrderData.net_weight = total_weight;
                newOrderData.volume = total_volume;
                // create split order
                this.#logger.info({
                    trackingId,
                    message: `Create split order for order id:${orderData.id} - start`,
                    data: newOrderData,
                });
                const newOrder = await ManufactumCoreOrderService.createOrder(newOrderData, orderData.tenant_id, trackingId, false);
                if (!newOrder) {
                    this.#logger.error({ trackingId, message: "Failed to create order csv." });
                    FbxError.throwInternalError("WMS_Order_4", "Failed to create order csv.");
                }
                this.#logger.info({
                    trackingId,
                    message: `Create split order for order id:${orderData.id} - end`,
                    data: newOrder,
                });
                this.#logger.info({
                    trackingId,
                    message: `Update order id:${orderData.id} - start`,
                    data: newOrderData,
                });
                const updateQuery = "UPDATE orders SET erp_id = \"\" WHERE id = ?";
                await DB.query(updateQuery, [orderData.id]);
                this.#logger.info({
                    trackingId,
                    message: `Update order id:${orderData.id} - end`,
                    data: newOrder,
                });
            } else {
                console.log("=======got into else block");
                const newOrderManufactum: any = {
                    id: orderData.id,
                    new_order_number: formatNumbers(
                        parseInt(await this.getNewOrderNumber(orderData.tenant_id, "Split")),
                        10,
                    ),
                    erp_id: existingOrderData.erp_id,
                    splitorder_number: number,
                    splitorder_position: position,
                    order_items: [],
                };
                for (const splitOrderItem of splitOrders[key]) {
                    newOrderManufactum.order_items.push({
                        new_order_item_number: await this.checkIfPositionIsStandardInt(
                            splitOrderItem.ManufactumPositionNumber,
                            orderData.id,
                            splitOrderItem.barcode,
                            tenant_id,
                        ),
                        amount: parseInt(splitOrderItem.amount),
                        change_amount: false,
                        WMS_Positionsnummer: parseInt(splitOrderItem.WMS_Positionsnummer),
                    });
                }
                responseOrders.push(newOrderManufactum);
            }
        }
    }

And here the code of the test. As you can see I mocked all async method and DB calls and still facing timeout. specifying different timeouts doesn't help
describe("getOrderDataForId", () => {
    let repo: any;
    let orderDataMock: any = {
        "id" : 303226,
        "date" : "2024-04-10T14:00:11.000Z",
        "erp_id" : "0089123048",
        "tenant_id" : 4,
        "shipping_service_id" : 2,
        "shipping_type" : "",
        "shipping_priority" : 5,
        "customer_number_erp" : "",
        "payment_method" : "",
        "currency" : "",
        "parent_id" : 4766580,
        "splitorder_position" : 2,
        "splitorder_number" : "98873524",
        "order_status_id" : 47,
        "bill_number" : "",
        "sales_channel" : "",
        "system_id" : 4,
        "created_at" : "2024-04-10T16:00:11.000Z",
        "updated_at" : "2024-04-11T16:11:07.000Z",
        "order_type" : null,
        "order_tracking_number" : null,
        "tracking_id" : null,
        "return_tracking_id" : null,
        "wmsx_status" : "unprocessed",
        "volume_measurement_unit_id" : 5,
        "weight_measurement_unit_id" : 4,
        "volume" : 25.65,
        "total_weight" : 2486.0,
        "incoterms1" : "FH",
        "incoterms2" : "Frei Haus",
        "net_weight" : "2140.000",
        "number_of_packages" : 0,
        "ship_condition" : "Z0",
        "shipping_point" : "V007",
        "sales_organisation" : "0200",
        "warehouse_number" : "HER",
        "desired_delivery_date" : "20240403220000",
        "timezone" : "CET",
        "description" : "{}",
        "custom_attributes_MF" : "{\"VSART\":\"SP\",\"ZTERM\":\"D201\",\"PAPERTYPE\":\"AT\",\"BUNDESLAND\":\"Niederösterreich\"}",
        "is_valid" : 1,
        "delivery_type" : "LF",
        "document_status" : null,
        "document_timestamp" : null,
        "carrier_mapping_id" : 2,
        "label_response" : null,
        "Flyer" : null,
        "cod_amount" : null,
        "cod_purpose" : null,
        "ps_sync_id" : null,
        "processed_fine" : null,
        "WMS_Auftragsnummer" : null,
        "WMS_Teil_Auftragsnummer" : null,
        "drop_off_point" : null,
        "error_description" : "Failed to detect carrier. Country short name: AT, sales organisation: 200, VSART: SP, ship_condition: Z0",
        "packaging_id" : null,
        "fine_status" : null,
        "fine_processed" : null,
        "channel_id" : null,
        "channel_sign" : null,
        "channel_no" : null,
        "item_count" : null,
        "warehouse_id" : null,
        "priority" : null,
        "cancel_reason_code" : null,
        "cancel_reason" : null,
        "carrier" : null,
        "merchant_id" : null,
        "integrator" : null,
        "order_items" : [{"id": 2290664, "amount": 1, "article_id": 2939, "article_name": "Balkonkasten Stahl verzinkt gross", "article_barcode": "2050000804168", "article_description": "", "article_weight": 2.14, "erp_id": "000000000000018996", "hazardus_material_number": null, "short_text": "Balkonkasten Stahl verzinkt gross", "sales_unit_id": 1, "sales_unit_iso_measure": "CMT", "item_hierarchy": "000000", "loading_group": "0003", "partial_delivery": "C", "overdelivery_percentage": 0, "underdelivery_percentage": 0, "movement_type": "601", "reference_movement_type": null, "movement_indicator": "L", "cumulated_batch_quantity": "0.000", "distribution_channel": "10", "division": "01", "plant": "0100", "storage_location": "L007", "profit_centre": null, "number_profitability": "0000000000", "sales_item_number": "000000", "item_number": "000010", "sales_document": "0852011163", "sales_document_item": "000010", "sales_document_category": "C", "document_date": "20240402", "order_date_customer": null, "order_date_to_party": "00000000", "date_of_call_off": null, "weight": 2140, "material_type": "HAWA", "article_width": 19, "article_length": 91, "article_height": 15, "article_length_measurement_unit": "CM", "article_weight_measurement_unit": "KG", "WMS_Positionsnummer": "1", "change_amount": 0}],
        "order_addresses" : [{"id": 1060667, "salutation": "Firma", "name": null, "first_name": null, "last_name": null, "full_name": "Schlosserei Bock GmbH", "company_name": "", "street": "Ascherstraße", "street_number": "0180795", "house_number": "10", "postal_code": "2734", "city": "Puchberg am Schneeberg", "email": null, "country_short_name": "AT", "contact": "02636 2303", "floor": null, "room_number": null, "erp_id": "0026824582", "county": null, "address_notes": null, "fax": null, "time_zone": "CET", "address_info": {"AT":{"COUNTRYISO":"AT","LANGU_ISO":"DE"}}},{"id": 1060668, "salutation": "Firma", "name": null, "first_name": null, "last_name": null, "full_name": "Schlosserei Bock GmbH", "company_name": "", "street": "Ascherstraße", "street_number": "0180795", "house_number": "10", "postal_code": "2734", "city": "Puchberg am Schneeberg", "email": null, "country_short_name": "AT", "contact": "02636 2303", "floor": null, "room_number": null, "erp_id": "0026824582", "county": null, "address_notes": null, "fax": null, "time_zone": "CET", "address_info": {"AT":{"COUNTRYISO":"AT","LANGU_ISO":"DE"}}}],
        "order_partners" : null,
        "shipping_service_name" : "DHL",
        "order_status_name" : "Carrier and shipping type are not determined.",
        "order_status_code" : "error_2000",
        "shipped_out_date" : null,
        "invoice_number" : null,
        "weight_measurement_unit" : "G",
        "volume_measurement_unit" : "CDM"
    };
    let responseOrders: any = orderDataMock;
    let splitOrders: any = {
        1: [
            {
                splitorder_position: 1,
                orderId: 123,
            },
            {
                splitorder_position: 2,
                orderId: 124,
            },
            {
                splitorder_position: 3,
                orderId: 125,
            },
        ],
    };
    beforeEach(async () => {
        repo = new ManufactumWmsxOrderRepository();
        ManufactumCoreOrderService.getOrderById = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(orderDataMock)
        DB.query = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(orderDataMock);
        DB.query = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);
        repo.calculateAnyISOUnitToAnyIsoUnit = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(1);
        ManufactumCoreOrderService.createOrder = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(orderDataMock);
        repo.getNewOrderNumber = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue("0088123456");
        repo.checkIfPositionIsStandardInt = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue("000390");
    })

    test("should update responseOrders array", async () => {
        await repo.getOrderDataForId(orderDataMock, splitOrders, responseOrders, 4);
    })
}, { timeout:10000 })

I've tried mocking all async methods and db calls with vi.fn(). Also, tried to change timeout.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
